# Are these patents still active? WO2010105586A1 and KR200297240Y1

Tags: expired, country, active

If these patents are still active, can they be used outside of country. For example, if I live in the USA, can I use a similar patent (cap pierced)? Or would I still face patent infringement?

I tried looking everywhere to see where it says it's officially filed or if it was expired. I see dates and codes but I have trouble understanding what they mean, even after searching them up.  I just want to see if it would be safe and not worry about committing infringement.

I would really appreciate if someone can clarify this for me! I'm scared of getting sued!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Korean application never became a patent and the WO number is for the PCT application. PCT applications need to enter the national stage in one or more countries to actually become a patent. I do not see that this ever entered the U.S. national stage

Patents are territorial. Other than some odd cases, they only constrain actions within the country that issued the patent. There are some small exceptions like things at sea.

However there may be patents other than this that cover what you plan to do. Just because there is not a corresponding U.S. patent there may be other patents by other inventors or the same inventor that could cause a problem.

One way to start looking is to look, on google patents for example, at previous work cited in the patent application at later work that google patents links to. These are things that the application cites. On google patents there is also a link to "similar documents".

US5005218A * 1989-10-05 1991-04-09 Ganz Manufacturing Co., Inc. Garment

GB2301017A * 1996-06-14 1996-11-27 Davinna Jennifer Bentley Securing garments

US6076194A * 1999-10-18 2000-06-20 Purkett; Varan C.
Wearing apparel system with suspended indicia

DE20018811U1 * 2000-03-09 2001-07-26 Lasar Raimond Body
jewelry arrangement

GB2381183A * 2001-10-27 2003-04-30 Peter Lawton Jewellery for pierced navels

WO2007142416A1 * 2006-06-05 2007-12-13 Seung Hoon Lee Headgear capable of being attached and separated ornaments

Comment: Wow, thank you for responding to this so quickly! I tried Google patent to search and I was only able to find these two. Is there another way you would recommend for me to research and make sure I search out any similar patents?